# How to Roll the log events into a file everyday in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core

I am currently using `serilog` for structured logging in my .net core application. I'm logging every single event to the Azure Log Analytics workspace. they have a maximum retention period of 730 days. I want to get log more older than 730 days.

now I want to rolling everydays log events into a file and want to store to a blob storage. how can I do that.

Comment: There is a Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage package, maybe this is what you want.https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage#serilogsinksazureblobstorage

Comment: that will be a nice solution obviously @GeorgeChen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there is already a Serilog release package [Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage](https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage).

From the [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.AzureBlobStorage/1.4.0) package, you could get it dependencies details, you could find it supports .NETStandard 2.0, so yes it supports .NET core.